# Can you identify the model of these eggbeater pedals?

Tags: clipless

I'm looking to buy these clipless pedals but the owner is not sure of their model. Can you identify what model are these? Would you also recommend them?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind that we don't generally offer shopping recommendations, we can discuss some things about these pedals. In general, I think Shimano's SPD pedals are very well established. If you ask a random group of MTB, gravel, or cyclocross riders what clipless pedals they use, I would bet that SPDs will be the most common pedal. I bet others will be on Looks or Time's ATAC pedals.

Crank Brothers has sold pedals since at least the early 2000s. They never achieved much takeup because they're not clearly better than the mainstream pedals, and in fact they may have some weaknesses. In part, it is generally difficult to compete against the big players, because the big players are a safe default for everyone. Nevertheless, Speedplay established a clear foothold in triathlon, and there are some road cyclists who really like them. Crank Brothers failed to achieve this.

An early weakness was that the pedals were held together by a locknut, and this would occasionally work itself out. If this happened, the pedal would fall apart on the trail. You could periodically inspect the pedal, but it's not reasonable to expect this of most cyclists (Speedplay has a similar but less serious version of this problem). The company have addressed that particular flaw. However, the brass cleats still wear quickly compared to others. Additionally, the cleat retaining wings may eventually wear down, and when they do, the pedal is a bit sloppy when engaged. Shimano pedals just seem to last longer.

Crank Brothers has historically had a lot of cosmetic changes. The top of the line version always has had titanium wings, body, and spindle. You could use a magnet to check, but those versions retail for $4-500, and we can assume you don't have that. Usually they would coat the spring and maybe some other parts in gold, and historically, some of the ti parts would be darker than regular steel (this isn't so on the current lineup).

I think they have usually offered a total of 4 different trims. As you go up, I think the materials probably progress from cheaper steels to more expensive ones, e.g. they may use stainless steel instead of regular cromoly steel. I'm not sure if stainless is an actual advantage here, since most other steel pedal parts don't typically rust. The bearings may also get more premium, but they should generally be adequate. In the current lineup, every center spring has a different color. In the past, I don't recall the arrangement for sure, but the more premium pedals may have had colored springs. Since yours is plain, I'd lean towards them being one of the lower models. I think the very first generation may only have had one model, and it was all uncolored steel, and you don't have the first generation version (and I had a pair of them).

Their customer service department has been fairly responsive in the past, and they may help identify the pedals if you email them a picture. They don't have a current document with pictures of historical pedals. You definitely don't have the something from the current version (which has the model engraved on the body).

Comment: Wear factor is most important for me so I will definitely look for other options. Thanks a lot. It looks like the C model though.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pre-2010 Eggbeater. I doubt anybody can identify the exact trim, but I also think it's irrelevant. As for my suggestion:

Crankbrothers pedals, especially older ones, are famously problematic. Cleats wear faster than steel SPDs, they used to have weak bearings, Eggbeaters specifically tend to develop wing rattle, etc. It's also not possible to adjust tension on them.

That said, personally I find the Eggbeater mechanism to be superior by far to SPDs, and to me the idiosyncrasies involved with riding them are worthwhile. You can clip in by stepping anywhere on the pedal, I've never had release difficulties in, admittedly extreme, wet sand conditions with them unlike with some SPD pedals, and most importantly, the float feels different and better to me, probably because your foot's lateral fulcrum is over the spindle rather than the front retaining cage of the pedal.

Ultimately, if wear is what you're concerned about the most there is an obvious candidate pedal for you - Shimano SPD pedals are by reputation almost eternal, despite their use of cup and cone bearings. Even a heavily used M520 or above will last you forever with occasional repacking of the bearings. The steel cleats they use will outlast your shoes as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site - great first answer.   Keep it up!